# Can an AWS Classic Load Balancer redirect traffic from a public ip address to a ec2 instance with only private ips?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a classic load balancer that has public ip addresses. Do the ec2 instances that it routes traffic to need public ip addresses as well, or will it successfully redirect the traffic to a private ip address? They're all located in different subnets in the same VPC.

The Classic Load Balancer allowed me to add the instances with only private ip addresses without any sort of complaints or errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your internet facing load balancers need public IP addresses. Your EC2 instances do not require public IP addresses, the ELB can load balance to private IPs. Private IPs sometimes make the traffic a little cheaper than public IPs, but not 100% sure in this situation.

You seem to have already done this, so I'm curious why you didn't just try it and see what happens.

Comment: Classic and Application load balancers always communicate with the instances behind them using the instance's private IP address, even if the instance happens to have a public IP address -- which, as you point out, is not needed.

Comment: Oh it's in production and I was 99% sure it was OK, but I wanted to check before actually moving traffic around since I wasn't quite sure how the Classic Load Balancer worked and couldn't find exact documentation on it's behavior. Thank you both for your insight!